# Giving out an imitate pronunciation of foreign words

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

Suppose I write a paragraph about a person named Richardo. Richardo's rolling r does not exist in English pronunciation. So the pronunciation guide I provided is just an approximation, not accurate pronunciation. How should I let readers aware it is a simulation?

- Richardo, pronounced like rre-kaa-doh, is a businessperson ...
- Richardo, pronounced close to rre-kaa-doh, is a businessperson ...
- Richardo, pronounced similar to rre-kaa-doh, is a businessperson ...
- Richardo, imitated pronounced as rre-kaa-doh, is a businessperson ...

Comment: Richardo, pronounced *Ricardo* with a rolled 'R'. Or, Richardo, pronounced like the Spanish *Ricardo*.

Comment: I don't aim to discuss rolled R or Spanish in my paragraph, how should organize the sentence? I just want let reader know rre-kaa-doh is not the exact pronunciation in the whatever original language.

Comment: 'Richardo (approximate pronunciation Rre-kaa-doh)...' Definitely not your last one.

Comment: Scottish people roll their Rs.

Comment: CV for being writing advice. If this was fiction, it would be very clunky indeed to break into the story to explain to the reader how to pronounce someone's name. "My name is Utta", said the pretty German girl, saying it to rhyme with a northern English person saying "butter". Better to rely on the reader's knowledge, and, if this may be non-existent, to re-think the whole thing.

Comment: There is no such word as 'businessesperson'.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is really asking for writing advice.